Launching instance from AMI creates empty boot disk
I'm trying to create an EBS-backed instance based on an AMI taken from another instance.
When launching the instance from the AMI, the boot disk is empty and contains none of the files and software that can be found on the original instance. It looks like the instance was created based on a vanilla Linux image.
I checked the following:

The boot disk is EBS and not instance store
The original instance was stopped when the AMI was taken
No errors in the process

What can be the reason for that?
